# In my Ubuntu 17.04 system why does /etc/resolv.conf fie gets overwritten on restart?

Tags: networking, dns, nameservers, ubuntu-17.04

In my Ubuntu 17.04 machine `ping google.com` did not work. So I opened `/etc/resolv.conf` file and its content was :

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

I added `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to the above file but it gets overwritten on restart of network service.

So as mentioned in the other answers I added `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` file and restarted network service. Now the nameserver value appears in `/etc/resolv.conf` file but `ping google.com` or `apt-get update` does not work.

Any help regarding this is much appreciated.

Comment: Similar questions on Ask Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012641/dns-set-to-systemds-127-0-0-53-how-to-change-permanently, https://askubuntu.com/questions/157154/how-do-i-include-lines-in-resolv-conf-that-wont-get-lost-on-reboot

Comment: Solved it.. @kimbo

Comment: Glad you figured it out! For future people with this problem that might come to this question, you might consider providing some details about how you figured it out. Could be a link in the comments, or an answer if you feel that's necessary.

Comment: Yes. I have written an answer about it @kimbo

Answer (score 2):

I solved the above problem by referring this : https://askubuntu.com/a/973025

> systemd-resolve --status

returned this

```
Global
     DNS Servers: 192.168.1.23
```

I wanted to change this. So after reading above answer, I edited **/etc/systemd/resolved.conf**

```
[Resolve]
DNS=192.168.1.1
```

and restarted the service -

> service systemd-resolved restart

Now **systemd-resolve --status** returned this

```
Global
     DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1
```